# TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: javascript, substring, indexof

Node is giving this error while checking the occurrence of a substring:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined'

```js
var withdraw = project.withdrawal;
                var uemail = user.eamil;
                var ans = withdraw.indexOf(uemail) > -1;
```

Comment: can you `console.log(withdraw)` and show result...

Comment: Your `withdraw` variable is `undefined`.

Comment: That means that `project` doesn't have a `withdrawal` property. (Or it *does* have a `withdrawal` property, but that property's value is `undefined`.)

Comment: you have a typo `user.ueamil`

Answer (score 2):

The variable withdraw is most likely undefined. Can you default it to an empty string with:

```
var withdraw = project.withdrawal || "";
```

That should avoid the error, but it might be better to check if there's another error causing withdrawal to be undefined.